# Substitute special character

Tags: shell, unix, encoding, scripting, locale

I have a special character in my `.txt` file.

I want to substitute that special character `ý` with `|` 
and rename the file to `.mnt` from `.txt`.

Here is my code:  it renames the file to `.mnt`, but does not substitue the special character

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls *.txt 2>/dev/null`;
do
filename=`echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1`
sed -i 's/\ý/\|/g' $i
mv $i ${filename}.mnt
done
```

How to do that?

Example:

```
BEGIN_RUN_SQLýDELETE FROM PRC_DEAL_TRIG WHERE DEAL_ID = '1:2:1212'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple problems in your code. [Don't use `ls` in scripts](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [quote your variables.](/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable) You should probably use `$(command substitution)` rather than the legacy `` `command substitution` `` syntax.

If your task is to replace `ý` in the file's contents -- not in its name -- `sed -i` is not wrong, but superfluous; just write the updated contents to the new location and delete the old file.

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.txt
do
    filename=$(echo "$i" | cut -d'.' -f1)
    sed 's/ý/|/g' "$i" >"${filename}.mnt" && rm "$i"
done
```

If your system is configured for UTF-8, the character `ý` is representable with either the byte sequence 
`\xc3 \xbd` (representing [U+00FD](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fd/index.htm)) or the decomposed sequence `\0x79 \xcc \x81` ([U+0079](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0079/index.htm) + [U+0301](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0301/index.htm)) - you might find that the file contains one representation, while your terminal prefers another.  The only way to really be sure is to examine the hex bytes in the file and on your terminal. It is also entirely possible that your terminal is not capable of displaying the contents of the file exactly. Try

```
bash$ printf 'ý' | xxd
00000000: c3bd

bash$ head -c 16 file | xxd
00000000: 4245 4749 4e5f 5255 4e5f 5351 4cff 4445  BEGIN_RUN_SQL.DE
```

If (as here) you find that they are different (the latter outputs the single byte `\xff` between "BEGIN_RUN_SQL" and "DE") then the trivial approach won't work. Your `sed` may or may not support passing in literal hex sequences to say *exactly* what to substitute; or perhaps try e.g. Perl if not.

Comment: http://shellcheck.net/ automatically diagnosed the first three problems.

Comment: ý is still not getting replaced

Comment: So that's in the file's contents, not in its name? Can you provide the output from `locale` and a hex dump of the bytes round the problematic character?

Comment: how do i provide that can you guide me?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Comment: LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=

HEX DUMP: 0000-0001:  fd

Comment: And the output of `xxd troublesomefile | head -n 1` (provided the troublesome data will fit on the first line)?

Comment: @ImranHemani The `locale` output should probably be added to your question instead of displayed in a comment. Anyway, see updated answer now.